# Struggling to run gsutil on a raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, gsutil

I have a simple bash script that pulls a few files off my google play financial records using gsutil.

When I run it on any of my laptops it takes a couple of seconds.

I've got gsutil working on a headless raspberry pi 2, with Raspbian (Stretch) and when I run the same script it takes a couple of minutes.

Even if I just run the gsutil command on its own (in order to be thrown back the help page) that can take 25-30secs (I'm connecting over ssh, which I admit may have a very slight lag, but all normal bash commands like ls are instantaneous)

I've looked at top and gsutil seems to kick off a python2 process that instantly takes 100% CPU (or all that is left idle anyway). I can't help but feel there is something wrong at this stage. Could it be the version of python I have?

Or am I just going to have to accept that the pi isn't up to it (I really find that difficult to believe as I don't see this as a particularly intensive program)

UPDATE :

The commands I'm running in my bash script are as follows

```
for type in sales earnings; do
files=( $(gsutil ls gs://my-bucket-name/$type/) )
for i in "${files[@]}"
do
    echo "$(date) - gsutil cp $i zips/$type/."
    gsutil cp $i zips/$type/.
done
ZIPS="zips/$type/*.zip"
for f in $ZIPS
do
    echo "$(date) - unzip -o $f -d csv/$type/"
    unzip -o $f -d csv/$type/
done
```

On my laptop it takes about 1-2 secs to pull each file, on the pi about 30secs per file.

Comment: Let's try to make the same procedure by using the REST API. I mean, share the code of your shell script (omit sensitive information please) and let's see if we can make it work without the `gsutil` tool. As you say maybe it's a matter of processing power.

Comment: I have created a sample shell script in which you call the the Cloud Storage function to [list objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) by [using curl](https://pastebin.com/DuZbFGKq) is this feasible to you? You would only need to install curl

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a try. However, I'm going on vacation for 3 weeks in a day or two so might not get to try it till I'm back, as this runs on the pi at home.

Comment: Just remember to tell me the results. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample shell script in which you call the the Cloud Storage function to list objects by using curl:

```
#!/bin/bash
access_token="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"

list=$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o")

echo "$list"
```

Is this feasible to you? You would only need to install curl. The function reference is [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list)